# How to make 2 separate forms collaborate with each other in symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a page. At the top there is a search box, that user can select search options in it. Search form will be submitted via GET method.

At the bottom there is another form, containing a collection of embedded forms, with one save button for all of embedded forms that submits them by POST method.

When I select search options and submit the search form, I can get the search form with selected searched options showing up by default, and the result form with search results in it.

When I submit the form of results by clicking save button, the previous selected search options don't show up by default in my search form.

So my problem is, I don't want user select search options after each save action... I want them to show up by default... So I understand that when user clicks Save button, it just submits the bottom form via POST method, and that's the reason I don't have search options there.

I've tried to store query() parameters from the search form and keep them in a session parameter, but I don't know how to pass this parameters to the search form, should I inject them in the request?!

Isn't there any sane approach to make 2 separate forms collaborate with each other in symfony2?!

Thanks in advance for your time! I appreciate any help or suggestion! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out that even when I submit the form in the bottom that submits the form by POST method, I still can reach the other form parameters using:  `$request->query->all()`

Kinda cool, I got the reason why it couldn't work before, because I was redirecting to page by appending parameters from `$request->query->get('search_form')` to the url, and it was empty...